# PDO params not passed but sprintf is

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Unless I am missing something very obvious, I would expect the values of $data1 and $data2 to be the same?? But for some reason when I run this scenario twice (its run once each function call so I'm calling the function twice) it produces different results.

Call 1: PDO = Blank, Sprintf = 3 rows returned

Call 2: PDO = 1 row, Sprintf = 4 rows (which includes the PDO row)

Can someone tell me what I'm missing or why on earth these might return different results?

```
$sql = "SELECT smacc.account as Smid,sappr.*,CONCAT('$domain/',filepath,new_filename) as Image
        FROM `{$dp}table`.`territories` pt
        JOIN `{$dp}table`.`approvals` sappr ON pt.approvalID = sappr.ID
        JOIN `{$dp}table`.`sm_accounts` smacc ON pt.ID = smacc.posted_territory_id
        LEFT JOIN `{$dp}table`.`uploaded_images` upimg ON pt.imageID = upimg.ID
        WHERE postID = %s AND countryID = %s AND smacc.account IN (%s) AND languageID = %s";

echo sprintf($sql,$postID,$countryID,implode(',',$accs),$langID);

$qry1 = $db->prepare(str_replace('%s','?',$sql));                        
$qry1->execute(array($postID,$countryID,implode(',',$accs),$langID));
$data1 = $qry1->fetchAll();

print'<pre><h1>PDO</h1>';print_r($data1);print'</pre>';

$qry2 = $db->query(sprintf($sql,$postID,$countryID,implode(',',$accs),$langID));                        
$data2 = $qry2->fetchAll();

print'<pre><h1>Sprintf</h1>';print_r($data2);print'</pre><hr />';
```

Comment: You need to bind separate parameters for each element in the in clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is the `implode(',',$accs)` function.

While you are using `sprintf()` it will generate a coma separated list and that list will be injected into the query string.

The result will be something like this:

```
smacc.account IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

When you are binding the same list with PDO, it handles it as one value (a string: '1,2,3,4,5'). The "result" will be something like this:

```
smacc.account IN ('1,2,3,4,5')
```

Note the apostrophes! -> The queries are not identical.

In short, when you are using PDO and binding parameters, you have to bind each value individually (you can not pass lists as a string).

You can generate the query based on the input array like this:

```
$query = ... 'IN (?' . str_repeat(', ?', count($accs)-1) .  ')' ...

// or

$query = ... 'IN (' . substr(str_repeat('?,', count($accs)), 0, -1) . ')'
```

This will add a bindable parameter position for each input value in the array. Now you can bind the parameters individually.

```
$params = array_merge(array($postID, $countryID), $accs, array($langID));
$qry1->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Kris has mentioned the issue with this is the IN part of the query. Example 5 on the following link helps fix this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php. I tried using bindParam() but that didn't seem to work so will use Example 5 instead.